# joda-time giving wrong day when parsing

Tags: java, jodatime

When I run the following:

```
final DateTimeFormatter format = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("E, d MMM y HH:mm:ss Z");
final DateTime date = format.withLocale(Locale.US).parseDateTime("Fri, 15 May 2013 07:57:29 -0700");
System.out.println(date);
```

The output is:

```
2013-05-17T10:57:29.000-04:00
```

For some reason it's 2 days ahead. I would expect it to be:

```
2013-05-15T10:57:29.000-04:00
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JodaTime uses the day field when parsing. The `17th` of May 2013 occurs on a Friday hence the output. You need to use:

```
DateTime date = 
   format.withLocale(Locale.US).parseDateTime("Wed, 15 May 2013 07:57:29 -0700");
```

Comment: So `"Fri, 15 May 2013"` is `Friday` on or after `15 May 2013`?

Comment: JodaTime _adjusts_ it to become `Fri, 17 May 2013`

Comment: Is it documented somewhere that Friday (day of week) has a higher "priority" than the 15th (day of month)?

Comment: There's nothing specific in the `DateTimeFormatter` docs. Similarly there's nothing in `SimpleDateFormat` to specify that it uses the date field over the day for non-lenient date parsing.

Comment: Doh .. that was pretty obvious. Thanks for catching my mistake :-)